# How to monitor memory usage of all processes individually (in Windows)

Tags: memory, windows-server-2019, performance-monitoring

I looked through the forum suggestions for my question but they were all Unix-based.

I'm trying to troubleshoot a Windows Server 2019 system that keeps locking up due to a "lack of resources". I need to monitor the memory usage for each individual process, since I don't know which process is the culprit yet. Is there a way to do that in Performance Monitor? So far all I've been able to find is how to monitor for a known process (i.e. you have to select which process you want to monitor). Any other suggestions for apps to use are also welcome.

I'd like to have at least three days' worth of logs in case the lockup occurs over a weekend.

Thanks. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you have a system that is hanging, you can configure it to perform a blue screen crash and full memory dump instead of restarting it. The memory dump should have the offending process, when !vm is used in windbg on the dump file.

Comment: well, it is for Windows also possible to use the performance Monitoring tool. you can then go into the past to see, what happened, it's a already existing system on board tool. Mostly never used by the most administration teams i know

Comment: Yes, I have already tried Performance Monitor. I couldn't figure out how to get it to monitor all processes individually. Do you know how?
How do I configure it to blue-screen? Do you mean do a non-maskable interrupt on the system once it's locked up?

Comment: I ran a PowerShell script through Task Scheduler to record the working set memory usage for every running process every two minutes and we had another resource depletion "event" over the weekend. Unfortunately whatever is causing the issue appears to have prevented the scheduled task from running right as the resource depletion began, so it didn't record what happened. My last entry in the CSV is virtually identical to the entries from hours prior.

I will force an NMI and take a look at the log next time the issue occurs but any further suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I figured out how to use Performance Monitor to monitor various parameters of each process individually. If you set the Performance Monitor to "All Instances" for whichever counters you add, it'll log the counter for each process individually.